# Radiobutton with SQL/VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have a question to do...

So, i have 2 radiobuttons called "Em Vigor" and "Anulada"

2 radiobutton when i click, they refresh a datatable, and i cant refresh the datatable with my SQL code. I did this:

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:RadioButton ID="FXvigor" Text="Em Vigor" runat="server" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="FXanulada" Text="Anulada" runat="server" />
</form>
```

These are the 2 buttons that i have created, and these are 2 if's with SQL commands. But i have search ong google and i cant refresh any of them.

So this is the code:

```
While FXanulada.Checked = True
    FXvigor.Checked = False
    If Not Rs.IsClosed Then Rs.Close()
    Cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT tbClientes_Apolices_Bem_Tipos.descrit as tipo, SOURCE.descrit, SOURCE.bem_id, tbClientes_Apolices.apolice_main_id, tbClientes_Apolices.apolice_id, tbClientes_Apolices.apolice_no, tbClientes_Apolices_Tipos.descrit AS apolice_tipo, tbClientes_Apolices.data_inicio, tbClientes_Apolices.data_termo, tbContactos.chave AS seguradora, tbRamos.descrit AS ramo, CASE WHEN nvigor=0 THEN 'Em vigor' WHEN nvigor <> 0 THEN 'Não está em vigor' END AS nvigor_descrit, tbClientes_Apolices.premio_total, SOURCE.tipo_bem_id, SOURCE.apolice_link_id, nvigor FROM (SELECT tbClientes_Apolices_Bem_links.descrit, tbClientes_Apolices_Bem_links.bem_id, tbClientes_Apolices_Bem_links.tipo_bem_id, tbClientes_Apolices.apolice_main_id, MAX(tbClientes_Apolices.apolice_id) as apolice_id, MAX(tbClientes_Apolices_Bem_links.apolice_link_id) as apolice_link_id FROM tbClientes_Apolices_Bem_links LEFT JOIN tbClientes_Apolices ON tbClientes_Apolices_Bem_links.apolice_id = tbClientes_Apolices.apolice_id WHERE tbClientes_Apolices.contacto_id = " & contacto_id.ToString & " GROUP BY tbClientes_Apolices_Bem_links.descrit, tbClientes_Apolices_Bem_links.bem_id, tbClientes_Apolices_Bem_links.tipo_bem_id, tbClientes_Apolices.apolice_main_id ) AS SOURCE  LEFT JOIN tbClientes_Apolices ON SOURCE.apolice_id = tbClientes_Apolices.apolice_id LEFT JOIN tbClientes_Apolices_Tipos ON tbClientes_Apolices.tipo_id = tbClientes_Apolices_Tipos.tipo_id LEFT JOIN tbContactos ON tbClientes_Apolices.seguradora_id = tbContactos.contacto_id LEFT JOIN tbSeguradoras_Ramos ON tbClientes_Apolices.ramo_id = tbSeguradoras_Ramos.ramo_id LEFT JOIN tbRamos ON tbSeguradoras_Ramos.ramo_descrit_id = tbRamos.ramo_descrit_id LEFT JOIN tbClientes_Apolices_Bem_Tipos ON SOURCE.tipo_bem_id = tbClientes_Apolices_Bem_Tipos.tipo_bem_id ORDER BY SOURCE.descrit, SOURCE.bem_id, tbClientes_Apolices.data_inicio, tbRamos.descrit", CDSI.SQLServer)
    Rs = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
End While

While FXvigor.Checked = True
    FXanulada.Checked = False
    If Not Rs.IsClosed Then Rs.Close()
    Cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT tbClientes_Apolices.*, tbContactos.chave AS seguradora, tbRamos.ramo_descrit_id, tbRamos.descrit AS ramo, tbClientes_Apolices_Tipos.descrit AS tipo, tmpClientes.nome_union AS cliente, CASE WHEN apolice_no = '' THEN 'PROPOSTA' WHEN apolice_no IS NULL THEN 'PROPOSTA' ELSE apolice_no END AS apolice_no_descrit, CASE WHEN nvigor=0 THEN 'Em vigor' WHEN nvigor<>0 THEN 'Não está em vigor' END AS nvigor_descrit, tbClientes.tipo_id as tipo_cliente_id, risco1.risco, tbClientes_Apolices_Permitions.group_code, tbClientes_Apolices_Permitions.user_code FROM (SELECT MAX(apolice_id) as apolice_id FROM tbClientes_Apolices GROUP BY apolice_main_id) AS A1 LEFT JOIN tbClientes_Apolices ON A1.apolice_id = tbClientes_Apolices.apolice_id LEFT OUTER JOIN tbContactos AS tmpClientes ON tbClientes_Apolices.contacto_id = tmpClientes.contacto_id LEFT OUTER JOIN tbClientes_Apolices_Permitions ON tbClientes_Apolices.apolice_main_id = tbClientes_Apolices_Permitions.apolice_main_id LEFT OUTER JOIN tbClientes ON tbClientes_Apolices.contacto_id = tbClientes.contacto_id LEFT JOIN (SELECT apolice_id, MIN(descrit) as risco FROM tbClientes_Apolices_Bem_Links WHERE predefinido <> 0 GROUP BY apolice_id ) AS Risco1 ON A1.apolice_id = Risco1.apolice_id, tbContactos, tbSeguradoras_Ramos, tbRamos, tbClientes_Apolices_Tipos WHERE tbClientes_Apolices.nvigor <> 0 AND tbClientes_Apolices.ramo_id = tbSeguradoras_Ramos.ramo_id AND tbSeguradoras_Ramos.ramo_descrit_id = tbRamos.ramo_descrit_id AND tbClientes_Apolices.seguradora_id = tbContactos.contacto_id AND tbClientes_Apolices.tipo_id = tbClientes_Apolices_Tipos.tipo_id AND tbClientes_Apolices.contacto_id=" & contacto_id.ToString & " ORDER BY tbClientes_Apolices.data_inicio DESC", CDSI.SQLServer)
    Rs = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
End While
```

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Where is located that code? Do you have an event handler to execute that code when your user clicks the radiobuttons or some other submit button? From your aspx above it seems that the radiobuttons don't declare an event handler like`OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged`

Comment: Yeah dont have any events, but its about that? How you can "Refresh" the datatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute code on the server side you need to declare an event handler for your radiobuttons and set the [AutoPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.autopostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to True otherwise the Radiobutton will post their new state only when the page is submitted again

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:RadioButton ID="FXvigor" Text="Em Vigor" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
                 OnCheckedChanged="FXvigor_CheckedChanged"/>
<asp:RadioButton ID="FXanulada" Text="Anulada" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
                 OnCheckedChanged="FXanulada_CheckedChanged"/>
</form>

Protected Sub FXVigor_CheckedChanged(sender as object,e as System.EventArgs) 

    if FXVigor.Checked = True Then
         ....
    End If   
End Sub

Protected Sub FXanulada_CheckedChanged(sender as object,e as System.EventArgs) 
    if FXanulada.Checked = True Then
         ....
    End If   
End Sub
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged(v=vs.110).aspx  or a full list of properties, events and methods for radiobuttons http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobutton_events(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Forget to mention that your need to set also `AutoPostBack="True"` see the update

Comment: Yeah, i search on msdn too, and i see that properties, but in Visual Studio i dont see any of that property they mentioned. and if i write, he marked that as a error

Comment: I will see where is the problem with my VisualStudio. Thank you @Steve ;)